# Grails unit testing custom codec using Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'd like to create a Spock unit test to test a custom codec I created. Most of the examples I see to test custom codecs are extending GrailsUnitTestCase to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this using Spock?

Comment: You must extends Specification, something like
```@TestFor(ImageService)
class ImageServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
    }
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SecureCodecSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        grailsApplication.config.acme.encryption.password = 'topsecret'
        mockCodec(SecureCodec)
    }

    @Unroll
    def "SecureCodec with string value #original encodes and decodes properly"() {
        when:
        def encoded = original.encodeAsSecure()
        def decoded = encoded.decodeSecure()

        then:
        original != encoded
        encoded != decoded
        original == decoded

        where:
        original | _
        'secret' | _
        ''       | _
    }
```

}