# Is UnitSpec still available in Grails-2.4.4

Tags: grails, groovy

Does anyone know if Unit Spec is still available on Grails-2.4.4? https://code.google.com/p/spock/source/browse/branches/groovy-1.7/spock-grails-support/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/spock/UnitSpec.groovy?r=1149

I wanted to use UnitSpec's loadCodec() method from within a Spec class of mine, but UnitSpec doesn't seem to be available anymore, is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you face problem using [`mockCodec`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#mockingCodecs) instead?

Answer (score 0):

@dmahapatro, I didn't really know there was a mockCodec method.

Thanks to your tip and this post ([Grails unit testing custom codec using Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124678/grails-unit-testing-custom-codec-using-spock)), I figured out how to use GrailsUnitTestMixin#mockCodec.

Thanks!